Error in Quantile Regression - Lasso Spline Truncated Multivariable
# load library
library(glmnet)
library(quantreg)
library(Metrics)
library(writexl)
library(readxl)

data <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Documents\\data.xlsx")

# Function to Calculater Inverse Matriks with Singular Value Decomposition
inv_mtx <- function(mtx, eps = 1e-016){
  mtx <- as.matrix(mtx)
  svd_mtx <- svd(mtx)
  
  diago <- svd_mtx$d[svd_mtx$d > eps]
  
  if(length(diago) == 1){
    plus_mtx <- as.matrix(svd_mtx$v[,1]) %*% t(as.matrix(svd_mtx$u[,1]) / diago)
  } else{
    plus_mtx <- svd_mtx$v[,1 : length(diago)] %*% diag(1 / diago) %*% t(svd_mtx$u[,1 : length(diago)])
  }
  return(plus_mtx)
}

# Function for Quantile Regression Spline Multivariable with Lasso one Knot
#quantreg_lasso_one_knot <- function(data, power, num_knots){
  data <- as.matrix(data)
  
  num_obs <- nrow(data)
  num_var <- ncol(data)
  num_pred <- ncol(data) - 1
  
  quant_values <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)
  
  # Identity Matrix
  identity_mtx <- matrix(0, nrow = num_obs, ncol = num_obs)
  diag(identity_mtx) <- 1
  
  # Forming Constant Values ​​for Matrix X
  constant_data <- rep(1, num_obs)
  
  # Forming Values ​​from Predictor Variables for Matrix X
  if (power == 1){
    pred_data <- data[,2 : num_var]
  } else{
    pred_data <- data[,2 : num_var]
    
    for (i in 2 : power){
      pred_values <- apply(data[,2 : num_var], 2, function(x) x ^ i)
      pred_data <- cbind(pred_data, pred_values)
    }
  }
  
  # Forming Knot Values
  subset_data <- data[, 2 : num_var]
  knot_values <- matrix(0, nrow = num_knots, ncol = num_pred)
  
  for (i in (1 : num_pred)){
    for (j in (1 : num_knots)){
      values <- seq(min(subset_data[,i]), max(subset_data[,i]),
                    length.out = num_knots)
      
      knot_values[j,i] <- round(values[j], 2)
    }
  }
  knot_values <- knot_values[2 : (num_knots - 1),]
  
  final_result <- data.frame()
  knots_data <- matrix(0, nrow = num_obs, ncol = num_pred)
  
  for (i in 1 : nrow(knot_values)){
    # Calculating the Value of Truncated Polynomial Functions
    for (j in 1 : num_pred){
      for (k in 1 : num_obs){
        if (data[k,(j + 1)] < knot_values[i,j]){
          knots_data[k,j] <- 0
        } else{
          knots_data[k,j] <- (data[k,(j + 1)] - knot_values[i,j]) ^ power
        }
      }
    }
    
    # Forming Matrix X
    mtx_x <- cbind(constant_data, pred_data, knots_data)
    mtx_x <- as.matrix(mtx_x)
    
    # Cross-validation for Best Lambda
    cv_fit <- cv.glmnet(mtx_x, data[,1], alpha=1, nfolds = 5)  # alpha=1 for LASSO
    best_lambda <- cv_fit$lambda.min
    
    # Estimation LASSO model for every quantile
    for (q in quant_values) {
      tryCatch({
        reg_model <- glmnet(mtx_x, data[,1], alpha=1, lambda=best_lambda, family="quantile", tau=q)
        
        # Predict value
        predict_model <- predict(reg_model, newx = mtx_x, s = best_lambda)
        
        mse_value <- mean((data[,1] - predict_model)^2)  # Mean squared error
        
        # Coef
        beta_values <- coef(reg_model, s=best_lambda)
        
        # GCV Calculation
        trans_mtx_x <- t(mtx_x) %*% mtx_x
        inv_mtx_x <- inv_mtx(trans_mtx_x)
        hes_mtx <- mtx_x %*% inv_mtx_x %*% t(mtx_x)
        gcv_value <- mse_value / (sum(diag(identity_mtx - hes_mtx)) / num_obs) ^ 2
        
        # Save result
        result <- as.data.frame(t(beta_values))
        result$GCV <- gcv_value
        for (knot_idx in 1:ncol(knot_values)) {
          result[paste0('Knot ', knot_idx)] <- knot_values[i, knot_idx]
        }
        result$Quantile <- q
        final_result <- rbind(final_result, result)
      }, error = function(e) {
        message('Singular matrix encountered at knot ', i,' for quantile ', q, '. Skipping this knot.')
      })
    }
  }
  
  # Export
  write_xlsx(final_result, 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Documents\\Quantile Regression LASSO Spline Truncated.xlsx')
}
# run
quantreg_lasso_one_knot(data, power = 1, num_knots = 150)


Can anyone help me?? i try to run it but everytime i run it, it has no result on the excel... the dataset i used from here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K8SanyWUn_M5x5m8vZTixqzaCpCNky9K/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103280654062940991227&rtpof=true&sd=true).
It says:
Singular matrix encountered at knot 146 for quantile 0.75. Skipping this knot.
Singular matrix encountered at knot 147 for quantile 0.25. Skipping this knot.
Singular matrix encountered at knot 147 for quantile 0.5. Skipping this knot.
Singular matrix encountered at knot 147 for quantile 0.75. Skipping this knot.
Singular matrix encountered at knot 148 for quantile 0.25. Skipping this knot.
Singular matrix encountered at knot 148 for quantile 0.5. Skipping this knot.
Singular matrix encountered at knot 148 for quantile 0.75. Skipping this knot.

and i dont know where the problem is...
